# Problema desconocido en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, grid

Estoy haciendo un programa que da un numero y una serie para la lotería en tkinter pero desconozco por que el editor me arroja la excepción `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` y no se por que, he repasado varias veces el código y no encuentro el problema espero que ustedes encuentren el error en el código o si es problema del editor, sublime text 3.
Creo que no es necesario poner todo el código pero por si acaso.
El código:

```
from tkinter import *
import random 


NumeroAleatorio=StringVar()
SerieAleatoria=StringVar()

def NumerosAleatorio(num, Serie):
    

    NumeroAleatorio.set(num)
    SerieAleatoria.set(Serie)


#--------------------Raiz----------------------

root=Tk()

root.title("Programa")





#--------------------Frame----------------------

miFrame=Frame(root, width=400, height=500)

miFrame.pack()

#------------------Entrys------------

SerieEntry=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=SerieAleatoria)
SerieEntry.grid(row=3, column=2)

NumeroEntry=Entry(miFrame, textvariable=NumeroAleatorio)
NumeroEntry.grid(row=2, column=2)

#-------------Label-----------------

TituloLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Numero aleatorio de la primtiva")
TituloLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

SerieLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Serie: ")
SerieLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)

NumeroLabel=Label(miFrame, text="Numero: ")
NumeroLabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

#-----------------Boton--------------------

Boton=Button(root, text="Nuevo número", command=lambda:NumerosAleatorio((random.choice(0,999999)),(random.choice(0,49)))
Boton.pack()
#Boton.grid(row=4, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

El error:

```
   Boton.grid(row=4, column=2)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la linea donde pone
`Boton=Button(root, text="Nuevo número", command=lambda: NumerosAleatorio((random.choice(0,999999)),(random.choice(0,49))))` falta cerrar un paréntesis.

Aunque hay unos que no son necesarios, podrías escribir simplemente `Boton=Button(root, text="Nuevo número", command=lambda: NumerosAleatorio(random.choice(0,999999),random.choice(0,49)))` aunque lo mejor sería que definieras unas variables primero y las usaras. Por ejemplo:

```
choice1 = random.choice(0,999999)
choice2 = random.choice(0,49)

Boton=Button(root, text="Nuevo número", command=lambda: NumerosAleatorio(choice1,choice2))
```

Así tu código se entiende mejor.

Comment: otra prueba mas de que mis ojos ya no sirven °-°

Comment: Jaja estuve un rato contando paréntesis. No fue fácil.

Comment: yo también los conté pero creo que se me pasó uno **._.**

Comment: De todas maneras me equivoque porque puse choice en vez de randint